# How can i use the Variable rechenoperator2 in the function gleich?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
gleich() {
    console.log("=");
    this.feld2speicher = this.feld1
    this.feld1 = parseInt(this.feld1speicher +""+ rechenoperator2 +""+ this.feld2speicher);
}

 rechenoperator1(rechenoperator2: number) {
    console.log(rechenoperator2);
    this.feld1speicher = this.feld1;
    console.log(this.feld1speicher)
    this.feld1 = 0;
  }
```

**I don't understand how I can use my variable rechenoperator2 in my function gleich**

Comment: can you provide the complete class? in the code you provided `rechenoperator2` is only available in scope of the function `rechenoperator1` thats why you cant use it in the function `gleich`, also how is that angular related?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could extend the function gleich() with some parameter like gleich(rechenoperator: number) and then you can call it with this.gleich(rechenoperator2) e.g. in rechenoperator1().

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment, please use the comment section to comment on a answer

Comment: its both, because its first the answer then the comment, but thanks

Comment: not really because the question is incomplete as you stated in your edited answer, thus we cant give a useful answer at this point

Comment: you can get it from the context, cause it is actually an angular class file, so this is one possible approach, another would be to store the value in a class member

Comment: i guess the povided solutions would would also work in a plain ts class, but at least it would be a class file with a this object. so i just tried to provide the best answer as possible with the limited information given here

Comment: @EricKrg Btw you're also not allowed to comment with a low reputation